# Proving a function isn't bounded

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ be a function to and from the reals. Is $f$ bounded?

I want to prove using the definition. Let $M > 0$ be given. Then there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that:

If $0<|x-0| < \delta$ implies  $|f(x)|=|\frac{1}{x}|=\frac{1}{|x|}>\frac{1}{\delta} = M$ whenever $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$

So is it correct to pick $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$ and I have proved that as $x$ tends to $0$ which, $f(x)$ tends to positive infinity, so it is unbounded.

Comment: What is the definition you're using for "bounded"?

Comment: @Sambo A function $f$ is bounded if there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)| < M$ for all $x$ in the domain

Comment: Small correction: the natural domain and range of the reciprocal function is $\mathbb{R}^* = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: It is trivially unbounded, for any $M$ we claim such that $|\frac{1}{x}| < M$, taking $x = \frac{1}{M + 1}$ suffices to show it is unbounded.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes you are right, I should have just they are a subset of the real line

Comment: @kodiak My question is whether the method I have outlined is correct or not.

Comment: @adisnjo The converse of that definition is "for all $M>0$, there exists some $x_M$ (in the domain) such that $|f(x_M)| \geq M$. So, once you let $M>0$ be given, you should tell us which value $x_M$ we should pick for this inequality to hold.

Comment: Overall, your use of $\delta$ is rather confusing. "Then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that..." Why? Where is this $\delta$ coming from? Moreover, "if $0<|x-0|<\delta$ implies ..." is not relevant here. This looks like it's coming from the limit definition, which is not applicable. You don't need to be fussing with $x$ in some interval implying anything: you just need to pick $x_M$ such that $|f(x_M)| \geq M$.

Comment: @Sambo I understand. I was just proving that the limit tends to positive infinity when $x$ tends to $0$. That implies that $f$ is unbounded, correct?

Comment: @adisnjo That's correct. In that case, your proof could be clarified by adding something like the following line: "To prove $f$ is unbounded, it suffices to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} |f(x)| = \infty$, so this is what we'll do." You could also adjust it to say: "picking $\delta = 1/M > 0$, we find that $0 < |x-0| < \delta$ implies...". This makes it clear what your choice of $\delta$ is from the start.

Comment: However, in my personal preference, a direct proof would be better since it would be more succint.

Comment: @Sambo Thank you so much. I understand what you said. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ was bounded  there would exist a constant $M >0$ such that
$$
|f(x)| < M, \quad \forall x\ne 0.
$$

However, this generates a contradiction since $|f(1/M)| > M$.

Answer (score 4):

The formulas that you've written actually prove something stronger, namely that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\; \biggl\lvert \frac1x \biggr\rvert = \infty.
$$

To establish that $f(x) = \frac1x$ is unbounded, we have to show that it is either unbounded from above or from below. The following applies to the upper bound, but everything works *mutatis mutandis* to show that for this function there's no lower bound either.

For each *potential* upper bound $M$, we have to demonstrate that there's *some* $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x) > M$. Your formulas show that it suffices to choose *any* $x \in \smash{\bigl(0, \frac1M \bigr)}$, but such a universal quantifier isn't strictly necessary here. In other words, we just need an example point $x$ rather than all possible $x$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thanks, but my proof does imply that $f$ is unbounded. Thanks for your help.